# Rigorous Proof of Slutsky's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics

I was hoping to type up my proof of Slutsky's Theorem and get confirmation on the excruciating details being all correct...

**Statement of Slutsky's Theorem:**
$$\text{Let }X_n, \ X,\ Y_n,\ Y,\text{ share the same Probability Space }(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P).$$
$$\text{If }Y_n\xrightarrow{\text{prob}}c, \text{ for any constant } c \text{, and }X_n\xrightarrow{\text{dist}}X\text{ then:}$$

$$1.) \ X_n+Y_n\xrightarrow{\text{dist}}X_n+c$$ $$2.) \ X_nY_n\xrightarrow{\text{dist}}cX. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

**Proof of 1.)**

Let $x$ be a point such that $x-c$ is a point of continuity of $F_x$ and pick $\epsilon$ such that $x-c+\epsilon$ is another point of continuity of $F_x$.

By the Law of Total Probability:
$$P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)=P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap\{|Y_n-c|\leq\epsilon\})+P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap\{|Y_n-c|>\epsilon\})$$
However, as
$$\{ \ \{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap\{|Y_n-c|>\epsilon\}\ \}\subseteq\{|Y_n-c|>\epsilon\}$$
$$\Rightarrow P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap\{|Y_n-c|>\epsilon\})\leq P(|Y_n-c|>\epsilon)$$
$$\Rightarrow P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P(\{X_n+Y_n\leq x\}\cap\{|Y_n-c|\leq\epsilon\})+P(|Y_n-c|>\epsilon)$$
Now note that
$$\{|Y_n-c|\leq\epsilon\}\equiv\{c-\epsilon \leq Y_n \leq c+\epsilon\}$$
Thus
$$P(X_n+Y_n\leq x) \leq P(X_n+c-\epsilon\leq x)+P(|Y_n-c|>\epsilon)$$

This inequality holds because we then have
$$X_n+c-\epsilon\leq X_n+Y_n \leq X_n+c+\epsilon$$
so
$$P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P(X_n+c-\epsilon\leq x)$$
and doing our limits
$$\displaystyle\limsup_{n}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x) \leq \displaystyle\limsup_{n}P(\{X_n+c-\epsilon\leq x\})+\displaystyle\limsup_{n}P(|Y_n-c|>\epsilon)$$
The far right term is zero by $Y_n\xrightarrow{prob}c$ which gives us
$$\displaystyle\limsup_{n}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x) \leq \displaystyle\limsup_{n}P(X_n+c\leq x+\epsilon)$$
As $\epsilon$ is only on the right side, and can be as small as needed and $x-c$ a point of continuity of $F_x$, we get
$$\displaystyle\limsup_{n}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x) = P(X+c\leq x)$$
The $\displaystyle\liminf_{n}$ follows similarly giving the same type of result
$$\displaystyle\liminf_{n}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x) = P(X+c\leq x)$$
Thus by their equivalence
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x) = P(X+c\leq x)\ \ \square$$

**Proof of 2.)**

Assuming $\pm\epsilon / \delta$ are points of continuity of $F_x$, and WLOG let $Y_n\xrightarrow{prob}0$:
$$P(|X_nY_n| > \epsilon)=P(\{|X_nY_n|>\epsilon\}\cap\{|Y_n|>\delta\}) + P(\{|X_nY_n>\epsilon\}\cap\{|Y_n|\leq\delta\})$$
Therefore as
$$|Y_n|\leq\delta\Rightarrow\frac{1}{|Y_N|}\geq\frac{1}{\delta}\Rightarrow\frac{|X_nY_n|}{|Y_N|}\geq\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}\Rightarrow|X_n|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$$
Also noting
$$\{|X_nY_n|>\epsilon\}\cap\{|Y_n|>\delta\}\subseteq\{|Y_n|>\delta\}$$
$$\Rightarrow P(|X_nY_n| > \epsilon) \leq P(|Y_n|>\delta)+P(|X_n|>\frac{\epsilon}{\delta})$$
And so by subadditivity
$$\leq P(|Y_n|>\delta) + P(X_n>\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}) + P(X_n\leq\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta}) $$
$$ = P(|Y_n|>\delta) + 1 - P(X_n\leq\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}) + P(X_n\leq\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta})$$
$$=P(|Y_n|>\delta) + 1 - F_n(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta})+F_n(\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta}) $$
Thus
$$\limsup_{n}P(|X_nY_n|>\epsilon)\leq\limsup_{n}P(|Y_n|>\delta) + \limsup_{n}1 - \limsup_{n}F_n(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta})+\limsup_{n}F_n(\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta})$$
Using $Y_n\xrightarrow{prob}0$ we simplify to
$$\limsup_{n}P(|X_nY_n|>\epsilon)\leq 1 - \limsup_{n}F_n(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta})+\limsup_{n}F_n(\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta})$$
$$=1 - F(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta})+F(\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta})$$
Let $\delta\rightarrow 0$ and so by properties of a CDF
$$F(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta})\rightarrow 1 \text{ and }F(\frac{-\epsilon}{\delta})\rightarrow0$$
$$\Rightarrow P(|X_nY_n|>\epsilon)\rightarrow0$$
If $Y_n$ converges to a non zero constant the proof remains by just substitution $Y_n=Z_n+c$.
The $\liminf$ again follows similarly.

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify how you arrived at $\lim \sup P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)=P(X+c\leq x)$?

Comment: Note that in MathJax and in LaTeX you can write $\displaystyle F_n\left(\frac\epsilon\delta\right)$ rather than $\displaystyle F_n(\frac\epsilon\delta),$ or alternatively you can also write $\displaystyle F_n\left(\frac\varepsilon\delta\right).$ (I prefer $\varepsilon$ to $\epsilon$ since the latter looks to much like $\in$ for me. And possibly for other reasons as well.)

Comment: Can someone explain how we change from less or equal to equal after we drop lim inf at the end of the first proof?

Comment: You'll have no trouble modifying your argument to show that under the stated conditions you have $(X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow{\text{dist}}(X,c)$ (as two-dimensional random vectors). Now apply the continuous mapping theorem, to $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and then to $(x,y)\mapsto xy$. (Or to any other continuous function of the pair $(x,y)$.)